# Post Op Most Famous Question

Tags: discussion, serverfault, blog

I don't suppose we'll be seeing any kind of post op report, blog, or podcast about [Our security auditor is an idiot. How do I give him the information he wants?](https://serverfault.com/questions/293217/our-security-auditor-is-an-idiot-how-do-i-give-him-the-information-he-wants) I would be really interested in seeing where a lot of the traffic came from and how everything stuck together. I've been watching the hit count on that question and it's insain! What other kind of novelties that this post brought up. As @MarkHenderson put it.

> Also, congratulations on breaking quite a few SF records. I'm fairly
>   sure this question has the most upvotes, the most views, the most
>   favourites, and its answers have the highest votes of any other
>   question on server fault. It also sat on the top of the Stack Exchange
>   hot questions for three days straight (now dropped the 2nd place,
>   awww). And all in 4 days!

Comment: Keep an eye on http://www.quantcast.com/serverfault.com to see if we get a visible bump from that traffic!

Comment: @sysadmin1138 nice find! Strange enough, I had to disable my hosts file blackhole to get the site working correctly.

Comment: @Nix - probably because quantcast do a lot of tracking of visitors, so if your hosts file blocks trackers, that'd be why

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Looks like there is quite a huge jump on that link you send for this week.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## So You Want some Data Pr0n?

This is all for this particular question.

Page Views:
[image]
[image]

Comment: hawt. Irony it looks like number 3 is hacker news... because why would you want to have good security when hackers have no idea how to search teh internets?

Comment: Taaaaasy tasty data.

Comment: @Nixphoe HackerNews is not what you think it is. :-)

Comment: Haha that's awesome, I'd be interested to know how much ad revenue it made ;) Crazy considering I only posted the question to reassure me of my own sanity that this was not standard

Answer (score 4):

Although that question ranks hugely in terms of server fault traffic, it doesn't even come close to some of the insane levels of popularity that stack overflow questions get ([4,350 upvotes, 280kviews anyone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)).

One of the things us mods have asked for over on meta.stackoverflow.com is to ask for the ability to see referral stats and a breakdown of traffic for individual questions (at the moment we can only see it site wide). Until something like that is implemented, there's not much to dissect unfortunately.

Comment: I like the idea that you had asked for on meta.stackoverflow.com. with the 280k views, are those views in such a short time though?

Comment: @Nix - no, that's over about 2 years, but still impressive

Comment: @Nixphoe The *accepted* answer has made the rounds on several non-IT blog as well.  Internet people loves 'em some Z̨̟͓͗͋̏̈̒͘A̯̞̰͖̟̮ͥ̆͐͐͑ͦ̔͒́͢Ļ̬͙̙ͥ̅G̵̶͍̹̯̮̹̱̟̍ͮ̚O̠͖̖̦͓ͧ͝!̶̨͍̞̙̝̀́̑͗ͦ͗̍͟